# Test for specific users with cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

How do I setup the proper permission level for this scenario with cancan?

Post has many Comments.

The post's author can delete any comment.

The comment's author can delete only his/her comment.

Currently I have:

```
authorize!(:remove_comment, @post)
```

and

```
can :remove_comment, Post, :user_id => user.id
```

Currently it only allows the post's author to delete the comment but I'd like the commenter to remove his/her own comment as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just do something like:

```
can :destroy, Comment, :user_id => user.id
```

Comment: with our setup here it turns out we had to override all the behavior:

can do |action, subject_class, subject|
  # ...
end